# How to test your deferred deep link in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have an app in which i have to use deeplink and deferred deep link.
I'm able to debug deeplink in my app but how to debug deferred deeplink in my iOS app.

How would i know what value I'm getting in launchoptions when freshly installing the app from appstore and how can i debug deferred deep link while in development ?

Is it possible to debug deferred deep link in development without making it to appstore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Branch.io, which we use a lot, you can manually replicate the process without the App Store.  When they say "Branch link" just use your own link:

> Deferred deep linking is simply deep linking into an app that is not
> yet installed. Once the app is installed, the context is preserved and
> the user's first app-open will have the deep link data from the
> original Branch link. To test this, uninstall the app from your
> device, click the Branch link, and manually launch the app from Xcode.
> You should be routed to the correct content within your app.

https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-testing

Answer (score 2):

In debug mode you can click on your branch link (maybe you can copy this link on a notes page or send it to yourself on whatsapp) and it will open the link on safari and redirect you to appstore (Don't install the current app from appstore).

Post this you can simply run the app on your device connected to your system via xcode. This will have the same effect as a deferred deeplink. (you can debug this in your app delegate, just make sure you are on the same network.. wifi or 4g as branch uses this for fingerprinting and might not run the deferred deeplink if this changes between the time you clicked on the link and launched the app via xcode.)

If you wan't to test as to how it will behave in production enviornment you can use test flight for the same. (Click on link and once it opens in safari install the app via test flight)