# How to test deferred deep linking for iOS app that's not yet on App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, deep-linking, deferred-deep-linking

I need to test the exact scenario of someone landing on our website with some referral code, and install the app from there, then have the deferred deep link be passed to the app when the user opens the app installed.

I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/54575630/811405 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54587263/811405 but they both require having an already published version of the app on App Store (even if it involves not installing that from App Store).

Our app is not published and we need that functionality on app's first release at launch. I've also seen [Does Facebook Deferred Deep Linking on iOS work, and how to test it before publishing the app on Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756642/does-facebook-deferred-deep-linking-on-ios-work-and-how-to-test-it-before-publi) but that involves Facebook and specific to Facebook's handling of deferred deep links, which we don't use on this project.

I have the Apple's app site association file in correct place and it handles web credentials and deep linking correctly when app is installed, but I couldn't find a way to test whether deep linking works or not whenever the app wasn't installed, user visits our website, taps the install from above (which we don't have as it's not on App Store), installs, and opens the app.

How can I test deferred deep linking without having a version already on App Store?

Comment: Hey man we’re in the same position. I see you asked this about 6 months ago. Did you end up figuring it out?

Comment: @vampiire we've ended up using Firebase and let it handle those.

Comment: Great I was looking into them or branch. Were you able to test it all properly through fire base?

Comment: @vampiire yup, it solved our issues generally about deep links and push notifications, including this particular one.